# Adding row to pandas dataframe where column contains additional value that should be another row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Simplified df where some rows contain additional entries in `another flavor` that should be another row:

```
   values more values   flavor another flavor
0       6         foo  caramel      chocolate
1       4         baz  vanilla            NaN

df = pd.DataFrame({"values": [6, 4],"more values": ["foo",  "baz"],"flavor": ["caramel", "vanilla"],"another flavor": ["chocolate",  np.nan],})
```

We need to add another row containing values from other columns, populating `flavor` with values from `another flavor`. We'd then drop `another flavor` to get `desired_df`:

```
   values more values     flavor
0       6         foo    caramel
1       6         foo  chocolate
2       4         baz    vanilla

desired_df = pd.DataFrame({"values": [6, 6, 4],"more values": ["foo", "foo", "baz"],"flavor": ["caramel", "chocolate",  "vanilla"],})
```

What's a practical way to do this? Is there an expression for this I could search for as a keyword?

Comment: try ``pandas.melt`` maybe?

Comment: +1 for `.melt`; `pd.melt(df,id_vars=['values','more values'],value_name='flavour').drop('variable',1)` works for me.

Comment: `pd.melt(df,id_vars=['values','more values'],value_name='flavor').drop('variable',1)` works but creates unnecessary row which we can remove by `df = df[df['flavor'].notna()]`. The df is huge and this risks incorrectly dropping rows of flavor that were originally `np.nan`. Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: `df.loc[:,:'flavor'].append(df.loc[:, df.columns != 'flavor'].rename(columns={'another flavor':'flavor'})).dropna()`

Comment: @wwnde Amazing. Adding `.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)` makes this perfect. Thank you!!

Comment: Ok , for the benefit of others,  added as answer. Feel free to upvote and accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the loc accessor to slice suitable columns and then append. You can sort values if needed.

```
df.loc[:,:'flavor'].append(df.loc[:, df.columns != 'flavor'].rename(columns={'another flavor':'flavor'}),ignore_index=True).dropna().sort_index().
```